# Can I reghost a file in Sharepoint 2010 using client object model?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I am trying to write a console application in C# using Sharepoint 2010's client object model. I'd like to reghost or reset to site definition some files. Is this possible and if so how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [SPFile.RevertContentStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.revertcontentstream) does this.